# Cannot access function inside function javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to clean my code a bit, so I create some small objects or libraries (call it how you want) like:

```
function myLib() {
    this.get = function() { ... };
    ...
};
```

Problem is when I try to call it like `myLib.get()`. It throws the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: myLib.get is not a function
```

I've tried to encapsulate the call into `$(document).ready()`, but it did not help.

Can you help me, please?

Thanks!

Comment: what is `myLib`  in `myLib.get()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

myLib is used for "libary", and you want to call this "get" method of libary.

Static instance is better in your case.

```
const myLib = {
    get:function(){},
    get2:function(){}
    ...
};
myLib.get();
myLib.get2();
```

Answer (score 2):

> so I create some small objects or libraries (call it how you want)

In your case you are creating a constructor, `myLib` is a constructor and not just a `function`, and you can't access a function's properties and methods directly that's why you got the Exception.

So you need to get an instance of `myLib` in order to call the `get` method or to access any of its members(methods).

```js
function myLib() {
    this.get = function() { console.log("get called!!"); };
};
let lib = new myLib();
lib.get();
```

**Note:**

And from the [MDN Reference for **Functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) you can see that:

> The `this` keyword does not refer to the currently executing function, so you must refer to `Function` objects by name, even within the function body.

Answer (score 1):

You should use myLib as a constructor ie:

```
var lib = new myLib();
lib.get();
```